# Write a link tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I'm trying to figure out how to write a link (as a

item) in rails.

How do I turn this into a rails link?

```
<a href='' class='her-sweep-to-bottom'>



     link_to dashboard_path(@profile.dashboard) 

         <br><br>
         <span>Dashboard</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Didn't get you. Can you please elaborate your question a little bit?

Comment: <%=          link_to dashboard_path(@profile.dashboard)  %>

Answer (score 2):

```
<br><br>
<%= link_to dashboard_path(@profile.dashboard), class: "her-sweep-to-bottom" do %>
  <span>Dashboard</span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "Dashboard", dashboard_path(@profile.dashboard) %>
```

Comment: but how do i get the class styling on there?

Comment: <%= link_to "Dashboard", dashboard_path(@profile.dashboard), class: 'her-sweep-to-bottom' %>

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<%= link_to 'nameoflink', {:controller => 'nameofcontroller', :action => 'nameofaction'} %>
```